Dots next to "Featured on Meta" / "Hot Meta Post"
I'm using Chrome on a MacBook and suddenly on MathOverflow there are dots (like to indicate items on a list) next to "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts". Here is a screenshot:

Is this intended? My guess is no since it looks kinda ugly. Have others noticed this?

We made an update to the right sidebar headers recently and there seems to be a cache issue that's lingering. We're working on trying to solve that but in the meantime, can you try doing a hard refresh + clear cache to see if that fixes the issue?

@Carrott I think this fixed it, thanks! I'll leave the question up in case anyone encounters the same thing.

I think that the idea that changes are not intended because they are ugly is, uhm, not always borne out by history.

As always, https://shouldiblamecaching.com is on point.
